# How to extrude a complex plane in a way where the new plane has the perimeter "thickened"

Tags: modeling, transforms, extrude

[image: The top plane would be the black plane and the bottom plane the red plane][image: Included Trinity Knot mesh render. I need one side bigger by about 2 pixels though. Maybe called tapered, beveled?]Just for a simple example.  Take a standard [Celtic Trinity Knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triquetra).  I want the top (like the black plane in the red/black picture) to be a plane in the shape of a trinity knot. The bottom plane (like the red plane in the red/black picture) should be the same shape but with an extra "thickness".  I need this to be a volume so I need the planes connected with side walls.  The blue picture is a basic volume made of this shape.  In the red and black picture it shows the different sizes of the two planes that I need.  I can make the blue picture's volume but I need to know how to make one of the sides slightly "bigger" or "thicker" like shown in the red and black picture.  In the red/black picture the planes are overlapped to show how the red plane is "bigger/thicker".

Comment: So do you want a red border like Harry's solution? Or do you want the shape to "grow" from front to back plane?

Comment: I need it to "grow" from front to back.  The colors were just to differentiate the back from the front.

Comment: Then you can take Harry's answer, select the outlining edges of the extrusion at the front faces, then hit X and choose _Dissolve Edges_.

Comment: Thank you works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the faces along the outer and inner perimeters and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Faces Along Normals*

[image]

While you are extruding and moving the mouse inwards, hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> so you get an *Even Thickness*. Then click to confirm. While the new faces are highlighted, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad+</kbd> to increase the selection and *Assign* the red material to it.

[image]

Here's the final result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you works great.